# php url shortening

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Ok i guess this is a bit of a general question really as opposed to a problem.

I am building a system where users can share their profile on other websites so i am wondering is it possible to shorten the actual url which would provide a link to their profile which would be something like this, `www.somedomain.com/users/profile.php?user=myusername` to simply cut out the users folder and the profile page and so something like this: `www.somedomain.com/myusername`

I have seen lots of url shortening scripts but they don't seem to do this, any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look into `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called URL rewriting and can be done using [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite). You would place a file called .htaccess in your root web directory and it would contain a snippet like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  /(.*) /users/profile.php?user=$1
```

Comment: OK, i think i may have got this wrong, a mod rewrite is when you then re write the url to something easier, but is there away of creating an easier url that can be given out, so whilst www.somedomain.com/users/profile.php?user=myusername is the correct url, if somebody visited the page www.somedomain.com/myusername it would go to the longer url.  if that makes sense or am i just confusing myself now :)

Comment: ok so this is my long url : http://my-cv.info/profile.phpusern=stan003 this is the code in my httaccess file RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  /(.*) profile.php?usern=$1  and this is the shortend url :  www.my-cv.info/stan003  however it shows a 404,  also as soon as i turn rewrite on the css stops working?

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, though i am still getting a 404 also when i turn the re write on it messes up the css on the profile page when you look at it through the long url

Comment: I'm not an htaccess expert so I think the next step is to ask a new question, link back to this one for reference, and post this code. Our Apache experts should be able to refine this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

this is called "url rewriting" - there are different approaches to do this, for example using [apaches mod_rewrite](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/). another way would be to manually parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - this would make your site work even if `mod_rewrite` isnt enabled, but is some more work.