# Mod-rewrite.htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I previously posted a question on to Stack Over flow and was lucky enough to receive some assistance to my initial question which helped me better understand that what i was trying to achieve was possible.

The previous question is here:  Visit [php url shortening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557955/php-url-shortening)

I am building a system where users can share their profile on other websites so i am wondering is it possible to shorten the actual url which would provide a link to their profile which would be something like this, www.somedomain.com/users/profile.php?user=myusername to simply cut out the users folder and the profile page and so something like this: www.somedomain.com/myusername

the code I have is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  /(.*) /users/profile.php?user=$1
```

Sadly two things happen, firstly the code doesn't work and secondly when i add this code the css on the original long domain stops working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`code doesn't work`: of course it won't because it's incorrect. Really wondering how did you end up accepting other question without properly testing it. Anyway take this code and replace your existing .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ users/profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked kind of, the css file doesn't work now on the re-written url, but does on the long one?.  With regards to the last question, i thought the problem was with my configuration but obviously it wasn't.  Thanks you

Comment: Thanks again. resolved the css issue and now all works perfectly.  Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is serverfault question.

1. Are your running apache?
2. Are apache mod_rewrite module enabled?

   debian: a2enmod rewrite; /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
3. Are enabled override for this directory? In case using default vhost:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
           #AllowOverride None
           AllowOverride FileInfo
   </Directory>
   ```
4. What are showing error.log?
   tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
5. Try simple version:

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^profile.php profile.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```